Calcite SqlStdOperatorTable.CONCAT not translated to SQL Server appopriately
Using Apache Calcite, I'm trying to generate SQL Server conformant string concatenation, but the result always uses the default "||" operator. I've outlined what I'm trying to do below and am wondering if I'm going about this incorrectly.
I'm building the RelNode tree with the SqlStdOperatorTable.CONCAT operator:
RelNode relNode = builder
    .scan("XYZ") 
    .project(
        builder.alias(
        builder.call(
            org.apache.calcite.sql.fun.SqlStdOperatorTable.CONCAT,
            builder.literal("A"),
            builder.literal("B")
        ), "TEST")
    )
    .build();


RelToSqlConverter convert = new RelToSqlConverter(MssqlSqlDialect.DEFAULT);
SqlNode sqlNode = convert.visitRoot(relNode).asStatement();
String sql = sqlNode.toSqlString(MssqlSqlDialect.DEFAULT).getSql();

However, when generating the SQL it results in the "||" operator which is invalid for SQL Server:
   SELECT 'A' || 'B' AS [TEST] FROM [dbo].[XYZ]

instead of the expected
   SELECT 'A' + 'B' AS [TEST] FROM [dbo].[XYZ] 

I have the dialect set to MS SQL and stepping through the code I can see the MssqlSqlDialect is set. However, I don't really even see any place within Calcite that this operator would even be translated to "+", so I'm wondering if I'm even approaching this problem in the correct way.
I realize I could get this to work using SqlStdOperatorTable.PLUS, but that defeats the purpose of making this database neutral.

So the work around I'm using is to change to using:
SqlLibraryOperators.CONCAT_FUNCTION
that results in using CONCAT('A','B') which is supported by the data sources I'm currently interested in.  Unless I'm missing something, there doesn't seem to be a way to add a datasource-neutral string concatenation call to the RelNode tree that can be translated correctly
